# java android androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to android.app.Activity error

Tags: java, android

I want to start new activity from my adapter so I wrote this code;

```
 holder.designCommentRl.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(main, manageActiv.class);
            main.startActivity(intent);
        }catch (Exception e){
            new tryCatchLog().log(e,106);
        }

    });
```

but when i click i get this error; `androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`

this code works on my other adapters. I didnt change anything. Why